# CloudFormation error [/Resources] 'null' values are not allowed in templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have the below CF Template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  Creating Maintenance Window for Non-Production Windows Server Patching.
Resources:
MaintenanceWindow:
  Type: AWS::SSM::MaintenanceWindow
  Properties:
    AllowUnassociatedTargets: false
    Cutoff: 1
    Description: Maintenance Window to update SSM Agent
    Duration: 6
    Name: MaintenanceWindowCFN
    Schedule: "cron(0 15 14 ? * MON *)"
    ScheduleTimezone: "Australia/Melbourne"
MaintenanceWindowTarget:
  Type: AWS::SSM::MaintenanceWindowTarget
  Properties:
    WindowId: !Ref MaintenanceWindow
    ResourceType: INSTANCE
    Targets:
    - Key: tag:Patch Group
      Values:
      - Group A
    OwnerInformation: SSM Target
    Name: SSMMaintenanceWindow
    Description: A target for demonstrating maintenance windows 
  DependsOn: MaintenanceWindow
MaintenanceWindowTask:
  Type: AWS::SSM::MaintenanceWindowTask
  Properties:
    WindowId: !Ref MaintenanceWindow
    Targets: 
      - Key: WindowTargetIds
        Values:
        - !Ref MaintenanceWindowTarget
    TaskArn: AWS-RunPatchBaseline
    TaskType: RUN_COMMAND
    TaskInvocationParameters:
      MaintenanceWindowAutomationParameters:
        Parameters:
          InstanceId:
            - "{{TARGET_ID}}"
          NoReboot:
            - "false"
    Priority: 1
    MaxConcurrency: 2
    MaxErrors: 1
    Name: Registration of Task with Targets
DependsOn: MaintenanceWindowTarget
```

And it reports an error like below:

```
[/Resources] 'null' values are not allowed in templates
```

Forgive me, I am new to CF but it would have been a much nice if AWS would have had come up with a Tool to identify what the error is and provide some with more helpful input to fix it rather than just last out the error!

Comment: The issue is YML is an absolutely horrible language and you will get indentation errors in each minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an alignment issue with your YAML.

Here's the formatted version, your `Resources` value was at same level as the resources inside of it which caused `Resources` to appear as if its value was Null.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  Creating Maintenance Window for Non-Production Windows Server Patching.
Resources:
    MaintenanceWindow:
      Type: AWS::SSM::MaintenanceWindow
      Properties:
        AllowUnassociatedTargets: false
        Cutoff: 1
        Description: Maintenance Window to update SSM Agent
        Duration: 6
        Name: MaintenanceWindowCFN
        Schedule: "cron(0 15 14 ? * MON *)"
        ScheduleTimezone: "Australia/Melbourne"
    MaintenanceWindowTarget:
        Type: AWS::SSM::MaintenanceWindowTarget
        Properties:
            WindowId: !Ref MaintenanceWindow
            ResourceType: INSTANCE
            Targets:
              - Key: tag:Patch Group
                Values:
                  - Group A
            OwnerInformation: SSM Target
            Name: SSMMaintenanceWindow
            Description: A target for demonstrating maintenance windows 
        DependsOn: MaintenanceWindow
    MaintenanceWindowTask:
        Type: AWS::SSM::MaintenanceWindowTask
          Properties:
            WindowId: !Ref MaintenanceWindow
            Targets: 
              - Key: WindowTargetIds
                Values:
                  - !Ref MaintenanceWindowTarget
            TaskArn: AWS-RunPatchBaseline
            TaskType: RUN_COMMAND
            TaskInvocationParameters:
              MaintenanceWindowAutomationParameters:
                Parameters:
                  InstanceId:
                    - "{{TARGET_ID}}"
                  NoReboot:
                    - "false"
            Priority: 1
            MaxConcurrency: 2
            MaxErrors: 1
            Name: Registration of Task with Targets
        DependsOn: MaintenanceWindowTarget
```

`Resources` is the only key that is required in CloudFormation hence this error.

With YAML spacing and alignment are very important.

Answer (score 1):

The template should be (indentation in `Resources` and `DependsOn`):

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  Creating Maintenance Window for Non-Production Windows Server Patching.
Resources:
  MaintenanceWindow:
    Type: AWS::SSM::MaintenanceWindow
    Properties:
      AllowUnassociatedTargets: false
      Cutoff: 1
      Description: Maintenance Window to update SSM Agent
      Duration: 6
      Name: MaintenanceWindowCFN
      Schedule: "cron(0 15 14 ? * MON *)"
      ScheduleTimezone: "Australia/Melbourne"
  MaintenanceWindowTarget:
    Type: AWS::SSM::MaintenanceWindowTarget
    Properties:
      WindowId: !Ref MaintenanceWindow
      ResourceType: INSTANCE
      Targets:
      - Key: tag:Patch Group
        Values:
        - Group A
      OwnerInformation: SSM Target
      Name: SSMMaintenanceWindow
      Description: A target for demonstrating maintenance windows 
    DependsOn: MaintenanceWindow
  MaintenanceWindowTask:
    Type: AWS::SSM::MaintenanceWindowTask
    Properties:
      WindowId: !Ref MaintenanceWindow
      Targets: 
        - Key: WindowTargetIds
          Values:
          - !Ref MaintenanceWindowTarget
      TaskArn: AWS-RunPatchBaseline
      TaskType: RUN_COMMAND
      TaskInvocationParameters:
        MaintenanceWindowAutomationParameters:
          Parameters:
            InstanceId:
              - "{{TARGET_ID}}"
            NoReboot:
              - "false"
      Priority: 1
      MaxConcurrency: 2
      MaxErrors: 1
      Name: Registration of Task with Targets
    DependsOn: MaintenanceWindowTarget
```